# How to make array.length read-only for all arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to change length property of all newly created arrays to read-only? Suppose I have an array

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

Changing its length property to read-only is simple.

```
Object.defineProperty(arr, 'length', { writable: false });
```

Now length of this array can't be changed. But this way I would have to write that piece of code for every array.

None of these work:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'length', { writable: false });
Object.defineProperty(Array, 'length', { writable: false });
```

Is it somehow possible, without changing it manually for every single array?

Comment: `length` you are visiting is in the instance not in the `Array.prototype`.So,you can define  custom `class MyArray` with `Reflect and Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not group those array in classes and just set that specific class into read-only?